# Consultar registro por id del usuario

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-views

Ok, quiero hacer la consulta en la base de datos dependiendo del codigo AutoField del usuario, automaticamente, traiga todos los campos de ese unico usuario (que seria un unico registro) Ayuda por favor.

```
def login_view(request):
"""Login"""
if request.method == 'POST':
    username = request.POST['username']
    password = request.POST['password']
    user = authenticate(request, username=username, password=password)
    if request.user.is_authenticated:
        user = User.object.get(consecutivo=1)
        login(request,user)
        return redirect ('index')
    else:
        return render(request, 'registration/login.html', {'error':'Ha 
    ocurrido un error de Usuario o Password'})
    return render(request, "registration/login.html")
#LoginPage
```

O sea, el usuario que entra a la aplicacion, solo consultaria sus campos ya configurado en un custom modelo de Django

Comment: Por qué quieres hacerlo por el id, cuando el username también debería ser único, consulta por usuario así: `User.objects.get(username=username)`. Por cierto, recuerda que si estás en Django 1.10 o menos, `is_authenticated` es un función, por lo que debe ser llamada así: `request.user.is_authenticated()`. Y para serte sincero, no sabría si en ese punto sería válido preguntar por `request.user.is_authenticated` en mi opinión retornaría siempre falso mientras que estés precisamente haciendo un login

Comment: Si tienes razon, retorna falso, no me deja logear y necesito saber si esta haciendo la consulta a la hora de logearme con el respectivo user, mira que tenias razon, en el modelo Tenia como "unique", el username, asi que puedo hacer la consulta en base al "username". Mira que tengo mal por favor o como deberia de ser, estaba viendo la documentacion de django, y tienen un buen ejemplo, pero aun asi intento con ese y no me funciona.

Comment: Lo que sucede es que no entiendo por qué quieres obtener el usuario en ese punto cuando se supone que ya lo tienes una vez haces `user = authenticate(...)` si luego quieres consultarlo, estás repitiendo la consulta. Además, si vas a hacer un redirect, no entiendo para qué obtener el usuario nuevamente. A fin de cuentas, en la vista donde redirijas puedes usar `request.user` para obtener el usuario y no preocuparte por el id o el username

Comment: @German Alzate Entiendo, brother estoy diseñando la logica aún, gracias por sus criticas las tomo en cuenta, ya me dijistes que por "id" no es necesario , ok, si lo hago por username ¿Como seria la sintaxis? introducida en el login? agradezco tus comentarios.
ef login_view(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        username = request.POST['username']
        password = request.POST['password']
        user = authenticate(request, username=username, password=password)
        if user:
(Tomando de referncia el user login de la documentacion oficial de Django)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Intentaré ayudarte a que aclares las dudas en el proceso de login. Lo más importante a saber, es que en un proceso de login no puedes hacer login por el id del usuario, pues los usuarios no se saben su id en tu base de datos, entonces intentar obtener el usuario por id para un login, puede ser algo tedioso tanto para ti, como para el usuario. Paso a explicarte tu código:

```
def login_view(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        username = request.POST['username']
        password = request.POST['password']
        # en este punto, la función authenticate retorna el usuario,
        # hay un backend que define como se comporta esta función, tu puedes modificarlo
        # pero lo importante es que sepas que `user` ya tiene el objeto usuario
        # por lo que no necesitas consultarlo nuevamente
        user = authenticate(request, username=username, password=password)

       if request.user.is_authenticated:
           # es decir, esta linea no es necesaria, porque user ya está definido,
           # y tiene además el usuario que se está logeando ya por el username y el password
           # por eso comento la línea, porque no es necesaria
           # user = User.object.get(consecutivo=1)

           # esta función ahora se encarga de coger ese usuario que autenticamos
           # y se la asigna al request, por eso es nuestro primer parámetro
           login(request, user)
           # ya podemos retornar al index
           return redirect('index')
       else:
           return render(
               request,
               'registration/login.html',
               {'error':'Ha ocurrido un error de Usuario o Password'}
           )
    return render(request, "registration/login.html")
```

Creo que está un poco claro como funciona el proceso de logear a un usuario en Django. Pero para entrar más al detalle, cuando llamas a `login(request, user)` Django básicamente hace una serie de procesos, donde escribe en la sesión y en los cookies los datos para que así la próxima vez que recibas una petición de ese mismo usuario no tengas que volverlo a autentificar, y es por ello, que en cualquier otra vista en la cual el usuario esté logeado tienes acceso a `request.user` donde `user` es el usuario que está visitando tu página

Espero que esto te ayude a aclarar tus dudas, cualquier pregunta, comenta

Comment: Muchas gracias, ya entendi, la logica del login, lo que yo quiero hacer es se hace una vez renderizado el "index" en una "def", usando los args del user logeado def index(request):
    args = {'user': request.user}
    return render(request, "timeup/reporte.html", args)

Seguido esto, en el template pondria las respectivas etiquedas con {{ user }}, me muestra el user, pero no los demas campos, ya estoy viendo que es, muchas gracias denuevo, muchas gracias!!

Comment: Sabes, que a la hora de modificar el modelo y crear el "superuser", me sale "error 1048 .... column..'numero_empleado' cannot be null", bueno en el campo del momelo le pongo null=True, y a la hora del request, en el template con {{user.numero_empleado}} me sale "None", y ese campo tiene valor

Comment: Me parece que eso que me comentas no está relacionado con la pregunta principal, si tienes otro inconveniente, no te olvides de calificar esta pregunta para cerrar el hilo, y siempre puedes abrir una nueva pregunta incluyendo la información necesaria para esa pregunta

Comment: Muchas gracias!!